# how to use Dataset in taskflow in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag written in the taskflow format, and I am experimenting on how to pass files between tasks, I read some info about `Dataset`(https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html) in airflow but did not understand what is the advantage over passing the file path as a string like in the following dag:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

@dag(default_args={"owner": "airflow"}, schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(1))
def my_dag():
    
    @task
    def write_output():
        with open("/path/to/output/file.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("This is some output.")
        return "/path/to/output/file.txt"
            
    @task
    def read_output(file_path):
        with open(file_path, "r") as f:
            output = f.read()
            print(output)
        return output
    
    write_task = write_output()
    read_task = read_output(write_task.output)
    
    # Set the dependencies between tasks
    read_task.set_upstream(write_task)
    
dag = my_dag()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In term of simply holding the information in an object there is , indeed , no season to use a Dataset Object.
The true strength resides in these cases :

### Data Aware Scheduling

Lets say datasetA is the source (or one of) of your DAG. you can pass the datasetA Object as schedule to trigger the DAG when another DAG updates it

### Lineage

In airflow you have a Dataset Tab which shows the dependencies of your data. Which is commonly called Lineage. That might help you figure out a few issues or onboard other people in the project faster.

### External Lineage

These objects are also used for lineage in other tools like datahub

## Example

Here is an example of two DAGs :

- DAGB is triggered when DAGA is finished
- they both have lineage support

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.datasets import Dataset

dataset1 = Dataset('bq://dataset1')
dataset2 = Dataset('bq://dataset2')
dataset3 = Dataset('bq://dataset3')

@dag(schedule="@weekly") # this dag is scheduled weekly
def DAGA():
  @task(outlets=[dataset2]) # this set dataset2  as an inlet
  def some_task(src : Dataset) -> Dataset:
    # src object will be considered an inlet as it is
    # a task input parameter 
    # we return dataset2 , it is also a way
    # to make it an outlet of the task (optional)
    return dataset2
  some_task(dataset1)

@dag(schedule=[dataset2]) # this dag will be triggered by DAGA completing
def DAGB():
  @task
  def some_other_task(src : Dataset) -> Dataset:
   return dataset3
  some_other_task(dataset2)
```

**In terms of scheduling**
DAGA triggers a state change in the scheduler for dataset2. This change trigger DAGB automaticaly. Allowing you to chain DAGs based on the update of data represented by these datasets objects.

**In terms of lineage**
dataset1 -> some_task -> dataset2
dataset2 -> some_other_task -> dataset3
dags inherit the lineage from tasks and we have
dataset1 -> DAGA -> dataset2 -> DAGB -> dataset3

#### Closing Thoughts

I have found lineage to be imperfect within Airflow. To have a DAG fully registered you need a dataset object(s) as schedule and to have a dataset as a task outlet ( defined in the @task)
The whole input param / return value of a task never gave me lineage on Airflow (i did not test external tools). Which is a bummer but you have been warned ! ^^

I Hope this answered the specifics of dataset objects and helped a few people along the way
Have a nice day !
**Quentin**